# If I unlock the FRP on my Samsung S7, can I root my phone?

Tags: bootloader

I'm having a lot of trouble to unlock the bootloader, but managed to unlock the FRP. Can I root the phone? Also, while on download mode, is it required to use a USB original cable?

My download mode info is: 
ODIN MODE
DOWNLOAD SPEED: FAST
PRODUCT NAME: SM-G930F
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
FRP LOCK: OFF
Secure Download: Enabled
Warranty VOID: 0 (0x0000)
RP SWREV: B:8 K:6 S:7

Thanks